# Set Constraints of Image using XCode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to constraint one dog image so that it is centered vertically in the container, which I can do. What I can't seem to get it is having it just above the halfway horizontal point. So I want it to be a certain fraction down the screen (say a third) on any device. I also want the size of the image to be relative to the screen size.

I want the image to be about what it is in the image but maintain its proportions relative to the device of the user.

I've tried tons of things and none of them work. Any help is appreciated.

[Here's the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSdGB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create an UIView and set the image to fill the UIView. After that make the UIView top constrain equal to the centerY anchor which makes the UIView below center horizantal. By using layout anchors for width and height ( not fixed hard coded numbers) you will make it's size relative to device size so doesn't matter using any device type. Post a graphical design if you need more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks! Another thing that was an issue was the size. I set the width and height of the image to a multiplier by the superview size, but it still appears way to small in the simulation. Do you know why? UPDATE: I deleted the app and reran it and it worked fine.